# Replacing string with \n not newline but slash is missing

Tags: linux, shell, unix

a.txt:

```
^variable=test\n
```

a.sh

```
#!/bin/ksh  
string=aAxdf\ndafsfasdf\n   
sed -i '/\^variable=/c\^variable='"$string"'' a.txt
```

output:
a.txt contains below contents without slash

```
^variable=aAxdfndafsfasdfn
```

Expected output:

```
^variable=aAxdf\ndafsfasdf\n
```

Comment: So a literal backslash followed by a literal n? Is `ksh` the only shell you can use?

Comment: we have bash as well but need the expected output as string value generated dynamically from another tool

Answer (score 0):

Quote your string while assigning your variable and double your backslashes, so they won't be interpreted as a newline character by sed:

```
#!/bin/ksh  
string='aAxdf\\ndafsfasdf\\n'
sed -i '/\^variable=/c\^variable='"$string"'' a.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. string value generated from another tool how we can append double slashes and quotes

Comment: @user1894029 String value? How does it end up in the shell script file?

Answer (score 0):

In your a.sh file, you will need to do the following:

1. Quote your variable value being assigned.
2. Escape the slash(es) with the escape character `\`

It would look like
`string='aAxdf\\ndafsfasdf\\n'`